# Java: Extracting sublist of arraylist based on pattern

Tags: java, arraylist, sublist

I want extract sublists of an array list based on specific pattern as mentioned below. Please advise.

```
ArrayList<String> Filelist=new ArrayList<String>();
Filelist.add("abc.123");
Filelist.add("abc.456");
Filelist.add("def.123");
Filelist.add("def.456");
```

Here I need whatever starts with the first index, say `abc` to be stored in separate sublist and whatever starts with `def` need to be stored in separate sublist. The array list will have multiple entries like these, so it has to create separate sublists accordingly.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or the classic java 7 way.

```
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String str : lst) {
        String[] splt = str.split("\\.");
        if (!map.containsKey(splt[0])) {
            map.put(splt[0], new ArrayList<>());
        }
        map.get(splt[0]).add(str);
    }
```

Comment: This can be optimized a bit: `String prefix = str.split("\\.")[0]; List<String> files = map.get(prefix); if (files == null) map.put(prefix, files = new ArrayList<>()); files.add(str);`

Answer (score 4):

```
Map<String, List<String>> filesByPrefix = Filelist.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.split("\\.")[0]));
```

Comment: what is :   s -> s.split    ?!!

Comment: this is `java 8` :)

Comment: I am on java 7. :(

Comment: can you edit you answer and give me a working code because i want to know how it work

Answer (score 1):

give it a try :
package main_package;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Stackkkk {

    static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> pattern_lists=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> Filelist=new ArrayList<String>();
        Filelist.add("abc.123");
        Filelist.add("abc.456");
        Filelist.add("def.123");
        Filelist.add("def.456");        
        Filelist.add("def.456");
        Filelist.add("def.456");
        Filelist.add("de1.456");
        Filelist.add("de1.456");
        Filelist.add("de1.456");
        Filelist.add("de1.456");
        Filelist.add("de1.456");

        for(int i=0;i<Filelist.size();i++)
            add_to_list(Filelist.get(i));
        System.out.println("number of pattern found are :"+pattern_lists.size());
        for(int i=0;i<pattern_lists.size();i++)
          System.out.println("number of value in pattern "+i+" :"+pattern_lists.get(i).size());

    }

    public static void add_to_list(String value){
        boolean pattern_found=false;
        for(int i=0;i<pattern_lists.size();i++){
            if(pattern_lists.get(i).get(0).startsWith(value.substring(0, 3))){
                //pattern found add it to this list 
                pattern_lists.get(i).add(value);
                pattern_found=true;
            }
        }
        if(!pattern_found){
            //create new list and add the value
            ArrayList<String> new_list=new ArrayList<String>();
            new_list.add(value);
            pattern_lists.add(new_list);
        }
    }

}
```